# Can JSON AUTO be used in TSQL to create siblings with children?

Tags: json, t-sql

I'd like to create a simple JSON hierarchy without using sub-queries.

**Goal Output**

```js
{
   "Sites":[
      {
         "SiteID":456,
         "Description":"Front Lawn",
         "Agreements":[
            {
               "AgreementID":89,
               "Term":"Yearly"
            }
         ],
         "Contacts":[
            {
               "ContactID":77,
               "Name":"Frank"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Note how Agreements and Contacts are siblings which each contain an array.

Is it possible to do this WITHOUT using subqueries? In other words, can I somehow tell `JSON AUTO` to reset it's dimension while stepping through the SELECT expressions?

***Sample Code***

```sql
-- Site
SELECT 456 AS SiteID, 'Front Lawn' AS Description
INTO #sites

-- Agreements
SELECT 89 AS AgreementID, 456 AS SiteID, 'Yearly' AS Term
INTO #agreements

-- Contacts
SELECT 77 AS ContactID, 456 AS SiteID, 'Frank' AS Name
INTO #contacts

-- JSON AUTO
SELECT 
    Sites.SiteID, 
    Sites.Description,
    Agreements.AgreementID,
    Agreements.Term,
    Contacts.ContactID, -- This gets placed INSIDE the "Agreements". I want "Contacts" to be a sibling of "Agreements"
    Contacts.Name
FROM #sites AS Sites
LEFT JOIN #agreements AS Agreements ON Agreements.SiteID = Sites.SiteID
LEFT JOIN #contacts AS Contacts ON Contacts.SiteID = Sites.SiteID
FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('Sites')

-- JSON_QUERY w/ Static (not useable for large datasets)
SELECT 
    Sites.SiteID, 
    Sites.Description,
    JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[{"AgreementID":"',Agreements.AgreementID,'","Term":"',Agreements.Term,'"}]' )) as Agreements,
    JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[{"ContactID":"',Contacts.ContactID,'","Name":"',Contacts.Name,'"}]' )) as Contacts
FROM #sites AS Sites
LEFT JOIN #agreements AS Agreements ON Agreements.SiteID = Sites.SiteID
LEFT JOIN #contacts AS Contacts ON Contacts.SiteID = Sites.SiteID
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Sites')

-- JSON_QUERY w/ Subqueries (What we are trying to avoid)
SELECT 
    Sites.SiteID, 
    Sites.Description,
    JSON_QUERY((SELECT AgreementID, Term FROM #agreements a WHERE a.SiteID=Sites.SiteID FOR JSON PATH)) AS Agreements,
    JSON_QUERY((SELECT ContactID, Name FROM #contacts c WHERE c.SiteID=Sites.SiteID FOR JSON PATH)) AS Contacts
FROM #sites AS Sites
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Sites')

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #sites
DROP TABLE #agreements
DROP TABLE #contacts
```

All the examples of `JSON AUTO` I've run into are rather simple:

- Flat or
- Last element has an array or
- Last element has an array, wherein the last element has an array...etc

I've searched high and low across Stackoverflow, Google, and MS documentation, but can not find any suggestions on how to achieve this, or if it is even possible. Has anyone had success in this area?

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid subqueries? What about they is undesirable here, when they are what produce the results you are after?

Comment: In almost all performance related documentation, people suggest looking for and changing correlated subqueries into joins or semijoins of possible. See some of the responses here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a4e384c-f8c6-45b7-a4db-c14827500fe3/subquery-or-leftouter-join-performance-wise

Comment: Clarification: In my real code, there is a lot more siblings, and each sibling has two or three join conditions. Each condition is based on an indexd field. I've taken a look at the execution plan for the sample code, and it looks fairly similar between the first and last examples. Perhaps I'll work up the nerve to share the real code, but I'm still curious if anyone has an answer for my initial question.

Comment: It's the misuse of subqueries that is a problem (like using them to get the value of a lookup value). For what you're doing here, a subquery is what you want.

Comment: Thank you Larnu. May you have a fantastic year!

Comment: Except that a correlated subquery still has horrible performance. Turned a sub 1 second query into 17-20 second query.